# Do I need Guhsl? Please read fully

Tags: sharia

I masturbate by rubbing my genital with the bed
In this process only the precum comes out but I get the feeling of a real ejaculation
Do I need to perform guhsl?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pray if you don't wash yourself fully with water (which means Ghusl in Arabic).
And try to stop doing what you're doing because it will evolve to bigger things in the future, look for a hobby instead of this bad thing.